# Using Grep in Bash Scripts to get codebase version

Tags: php, bash, drupal

Suppose I have written a bash script wherein I have mentioned the version of my codebase.(say under settings.php). Now I want a bash script which will fetch the codebase version mentioned in the other bash script, how can i use 'Grep' command in this case. I have tried out, but without success. Please help.

Comment: Please pose the code you've tried so far so we can see what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Please expose some code examples, so I could figure out solution.

Answer (score 0):

`grep` is a line-matching tool. It will output the whole line where it finds matching substring. But in `bash` script you can read output from it, BUT using `read` will give you only last line from entire `grep` output. For example if output from `grep "version"` is:

```
version:1.1.1
module_version:0.1.2
```

Then `read` will catch only last line `module_version:0.1.2`, but not the first.

Assuming case in your file you have line `version:1.1.1`. In bash script you can do

```
cat your_file | grep 'version'
read LINE
```

That will give you variable `LINE="version:1.1.1"`. And then you will need to parse the resulting string. But since i am not sure what is the format of string i cannot give you exact code how to parse it.

After getting more details here is suitable solution:

```
db_version=$(cat $portal_codebase_version/sites/default/settings.php | grep "$GLOBALS['sdm_version']" | sed -n -e "s/^[^=]*= '[^ ]* \(.*\)';$/\1/p")
```

Which gives you

```
$ echo $db_version 
3.8.0.4
$
```

Comment: dbversion= `grep ^\\$GLOBALS['sdm_version'] $variable/sites/default/settings.php  2> /dev/null | sed -n 's/.*\/\(.*\):.*/\1/p'`

Comment: adding echo $dbversion after that.

Comment: @ezazhussain how the whole line which you are trying to parse does look like?

Comment: I have put this line in a different bash script.-> echo "\$GLOBALS['sdm_version'] = 'generic 3.8.0.4';" >> sites/default/settings.php

Comment: now I want to get the output of this line in a different bash script. Tried using 'Grep', but no avail. In the  second script, I have tried out like the one I have posted before.dbversion= `grep ^\\$GLOBALS['sdm_version'] $portal_codebase_version/sites/default/settings.php  2> /dev/null | sed -n 's/.*\/\(.*\):.*/\1/p'`
    echo $dbversion

Comment: @ezazhussain Alright, and you need to get in `$dbversion` follwing string `generic 3.8.0.4`. Am I right?

Comment: You could do it like this `db_version=$(cat $portal_codebase_version/sites/default/settings.php  | grep "$GLOBALS['sdm_version']" | sed -n 's#^[^=]*=\(.*\);$#\1#p' | sed -n 's#\([a-zA-Z0-9 .]\)*#\1#p')`. Which gives you `db_version=generic 3.8.0.4`.

Comment: @ezazhussain I updated the answer. Hope this is what you are looking for. If you need different part of string you can play around with `sed`

Comment: I just need the number only i.e 3.8.0.4 . Would you mind providing an exact solution?

Comment: @ezazhussain as said be4 - welcome. FYI here normally valid answers are marked as accepted. i am not requesting you to do so, just let you know. Otherwise people will not be interested answering your questions and if someone will search for same issue they will not find it.